# Insert new object into array if match name is not present

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to insert a new object to the array, if the name is not exists in the any array of object record. Also to remove the object from array if not present in input data

Here is the Mongo document looks like

```
{
    "_id":  "63fc92f882fd1c39e7374634",
    "assignment": [{
        "email": "mail1@mail.com",
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "address1",
        "accesskey" : 12345
    },{
        "email": "mail2@mail.com",
        "name": "name2",
        "address": "address2",
        "accesskey" : 23456
    },{
        "email": "mail3@mail.com",
        "name": "name3",
        "address": "address3",
        "accesskey" : 55852
    }],
    "bookingid": 2183530
}
```

The update request of the input data looks like

```
{
    "_id":  "63fc92f882fd1c39e7374634",
    "assignment": [{
        "email": "mail1@mail.com",
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "address1"
    },{
        "email": "mail3@mail.com",
        "name": "name3",
        "address": "address3"
    },{
        "email": "mail4@mail.com",
        "name": "name4",
        "address": "address4"
    }],
    "bookingid": 2183530
}
```

Expecting the output document to look like

```
{
    "_id":  "63fc92f882fd1c39e7374634",
    "assignment": [{
        "email": "mail1@mail.com",
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "address1",
        "accesskey" : 12345
    },{
        "email": "mail3@mail.com",
        "name": "name3",
        "address": "address3",
        "accesskey" : 55852
    },{
        "email": "mail4@mail.com",
        "name": "name4",
        "address": "address4",
        "accesskey" : 33333
    }],
    "bookingid": 2183530
}
```

The email : mail2@mail.com needs to be removed as it is not present in the input data and the object with the email : mail4@mail.com needs to added to the DB record.

```
for (let c = 0; c < assignment.length; c++) {
db.findByIdAndUpdate({ '_id': id,
            "assignment.email": {
              $ne: assignment[c].email
            }}, 
{ $push: {$assignment:{"email" : assignment[c].email,
"name" : assignment[c].name,  "address" : assignment[c].address}}); 
}
```

I get the final document with 7 objects.

I have tried to loop the assignment array and push new objects, but the object is pushed for email which already exists ends up giving total 7 Objects.

Comment: Why not simply replace with your payload like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bt2fwYK0tNX)?

Comment: Yes, I was earlier replacing the payload but now we have a field called accesskey which needs to be retained and is not available in the payload. I can bind this value and replace but wants to check the possibility of using Mongo query. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: What is the criteria of "exists"? by the field `email`?

Comment: Yes email is the crtieria

Comment: Now using aggregate, I am able to add new objects but stuck on removing objects not included in payload https://mongoplayground.net/p/sNpWGD6iVf2

Comment: You may want to consider a schema like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yy5uuNaYb51) if you are doing operations on `assignment` level very frequently.

Comment: Understood. I will consider changing the schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set operations to determine which records to pick from assignments array and payload array. For update case, use `$mergeObjects` to perform the update. For insert case, use `$concatArrays` to perform the union.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "63fc92f882fd1c39e7374634"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      payload: [
        {
          "email": "mail1@mail.com",
          "name": "name1",
          "address": "address1"
        },
        {
          "email": "mail3@mail.com",
          "name": "name3",
          "address": "address3"
        },
        {
          "email": "mail4@mail.com",
          "name": "name4",
          "address": "address4"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      bookingid: 1,
      fromAssignment: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$assignment",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$a.email",
              "$payload.email"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      updateFromPayload: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$payload",
          "as": "p",
          "cond": {
            $in: [
              "$$p.email",
              "$assignment.email"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      newFromPayload: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$payload",
          "as": "p",
          "cond": {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$p.email",
                "$assignment.email"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fromAssignment"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$updateFromPayload"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$fromAssignment.email",
          "$updateFromPayload.email"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      bookingid: {
        $first: "$bookingid"
      },
      assignment: {
        $push: {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$fromAssignment",
            "$updateFromPayload"
          ]
        }
      },
      newFromPayload: {
        $first: "$newFromPayload"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      assignment: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$assignment",
          "$newFromPayload"
        ]
      },
      newFromPayload: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dDamAWU7lCY)